# nodejs concurrency synchronous execution

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, websocket, synchronization

I've two WebSockets getting data asynchronously, every time I get some message from the sockets I execute some code in CompareData.

The problem is that CompareData should be executed synchronously, or (better) only if it is not already running

This is my code:

```
function CompareData(data) {
    console.log('data ', data);
    AsyncFunction();
};
ws1 = new WebSocket(WS1_URL);
ws2 = new WebSocket(WS2_URL);
ws1.on('message', (data) => {
    CompareData(data);
});
ws2.on('message', (data) => {
    CompareData(data);
});
```

Can you help me, please? I'm very new to NodeJs

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to force an async function into synchronicity. Can you elaborate on why you wish to achieve this behavior ?

Answer (score 2):

**Node.js is single threaded**.  So you don't really get true concurrency issues occurring in Node programs as you might in other languages.  In your example, there can only be at most one WebSocket callback for CompareData occurring at any given time.

Comment: As long as `CompareData()` has no asynchronous functions in it.

Comment: CompareData has async functions in it

Comment: Right, those inner async function get called *after* CompareData has returned.  There will only ever be one callback going on at a time.  Can you elaborate on what you are really trying to guard against?

Answer (score 0):

You should not make synchronous call in node.js but you can make those call sequential. See below example might be helpful.

```js
var messages = [];
var inProgress = false;

function CompareData(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do some stuff and resolve
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(data);
    }, 1000);
  });
};

const start = async () => {
  if (!inProgress) {
    if (messages.length !== 0) {
      inProgress = true;
      try {
        const data = await CompareData(messages.shift());
        console.log(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      inProgress = false;
      await start();
    }else{
      console.log('Process Done');
    }
  }
}

const handler = (data) => {
  messages.push(data);
  start();
}

handler(1);
handler(2);
handler(3);
handler(4);

// ws1 = new WebSocket(WS1_URL);
// ws2 = new WebSocket(WS2_URL);
// ws1.on('message', handler);
// ws2.on('message', handler);
```

Comment: Thank you for your code, is this example valid if in CompareData there are also async functions?

Comment: CompareData is async then only you have to otherwise you can directly call. it'll be sync by default.

Comment: If I choose your approach messages received from sockets are put in a queue... I should skip all messages received while CompareData is running; please consider that CompareData does async stuff and it complete execution could be of five seconds. Only when CompareData is finished I should start reconsidering messages from sockets.

Comment: In that case, you don't have to maintain a queue, you can simply check inProgress flag is true then skip if it's false then process.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not very practical about promises and anything else related to await and async... I'm testing new code, I hope it works flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

You should use some mutex in order to avoid that two async operations of `compareData` are executed at the same time, like [`node-mutex`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-mutex) or [`mutexify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mutexify).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions are:

1. First of all, you need to know when CompareData is finished. Reorganize your code to use promises or callbacks. If you're using third-party async functions, I'm almost sure they provide some feedback on completion - **This is a must have in async world**
2. Add `inProgress = false` flag somewhere to serve for you as simple lock. As someone posted, JS is single-threaded and you're guaranteed that your code won't get interrupted in the middle of operation. Thanks to that you can use really simple locks instead of complicated os-based mutexes known from multithreaded 
   langs.
3. In `ws.on(...)` check if `inProgress` is set. If not, lock it and run CompareData
4. In CompareData completion callback or on promise resolution set *inProgress* back to false, so you're no longer ignoring incoming data.

If you can simply discard the data, there is no need to complicate this scenario with extra queues, mutexes, etc.

If you need to serve it all, then queue incoming data and serve next piece after completion callback is fired.

This is basically what Rahul's suggests, but he uses features that are not established in current version of standard, so don't use it if you're not transpiling your code.